# connecting Ubuntu host and Windows 7 guest with samba

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, samba, qemu, linux-kvm

I have a Windows 7 guest OS on a Ubuntu 22.04 host and I'm trying to set up a Samba connection to transfer files between them. This is how I understand it should work:

On the Ubuntu host:
1: install samba: `sudo apt install samba`
2: make a sambashare directory: `mkdir ~username/sambashare` (with rwx for everyone)
3: add this to the configuration file `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
[sambashare]
    comment = Samba on Ubuntu
    path = /home/username/sambashare
    read only = no
    browsable = yes
```

4: add username to samba: `sudo smbpasswd -a username`
5: allow samba traffic: `sudo ufw allow samba`
6: restart samba: `sudo service smbd restart`

Then in the Windows guest (logged in as either 'admin' or 'user'):
1: open "Explorer"
2: right-click on "Computer" and select "Open network drive..."
3: for "Folder" type `\\10.0.2.2\sambashare` and tick "Connect using different credentials"

Then the "Enter Network Password" dialog comes with the user name "KVM-QEMU-WIN7\username" and lets me enter a password. I use the password that I set in the Ubuntu host.

After step 3, a message "Attempting to connect to \10.0.2.2\sambashare" appears (at the same time as the dialog), but it does not succeed.

It was reassuring to see the Ubuntu "username" in the password dialog, suggesting that there is a connection (I previously had a user on the guest OS, but removed them). But why does the login fail after that? (the files in `/var/log/samba` on the host show no evidence that the login attempt ever got through)

Comment: In the firewall rules in my setup I have sudo ufw allow samba for the firewall rules; that it, I added the rule as Admin. You may need to do this. Otherwise your setup looks very similar to mine. Also remember Windows 7 uses older SMB which may be getting in the way.

Comment: Thanks @John, I think it may be the wold W7 settings rather than the Ubuntu setup, either the old protocol or the security settings (I set the ufw rules with sudo, corrected in the post). Is there a place you know where those can be viewed/changed?

Comment: I just edit in smb.conf

Comment: How was the IP address 10.0.2.2 determined? Does the guest OS see any packets from the host on tcp port 445?

Comment: @u1868_grawity, I thought that 10.0.2.2 is the address for samba servers? Not sure how to find it if it's not. On the windows guest I have internet access, but I'm not finding windows shares.

Comment: @John sorry I thought you mening changing settings in Windows. Would my Ubuntu-side settings need changes?

Comment: If you wish to map FROM Windows TO Ubuntu, you need to set up Samba entirely on Ubuntu.  You can map FROM Ubuntu TO Windows with SMB://ipaddress/folder

Comment: Thanks, my situation is the second. But I get the idea that the samba that comes with w7 is the problem, wonder if that could be upgraded somehow.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you try to connect as `"KVM-QEMU-WIN7\username"`, which means user `username` on machine `KVM-QEMU-WIN7`, probably the **windows guest** machine. You need to say that the `username` belongs to the **linux host**, like `"10.0.2.2\username"`.

Otherwise I would try the built-in file sharing of the virtualizer like this
https://ostechnix.com/setup-a-shared-folder-between-kvm-host-and-guest/

Comment: I think this is what I need to do,yes. But the problems I have are that 1) in windows there are no other computers in the Network 'folder' and I don't know the name/address of the Linux host there, and 2) the virtualiser software works only for W8 and up...

Comment: 1. The "samba" way. The name of the Linux machine should be found out from the network configuration of the virtualizer. If it is "bridge", then the "external" IP of the Linux host. If it is "NAT", then probably the "default gateway" of the Windows guest. Anyway you should be able to "ping" that IP. The address 10.0.2.2 is just an example of a "private IP address" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network), anyone can use such address and be sure no public server in the internet will have this address. You can use it for your server, but you have to set it yourself.

Comment: 2. Virtualizer way. I know how it works with VirtualBox, there (even in Windows XP) you have under "My Network Places" -> "Entire Network" -> ("Microsoft Windows Network" and "VirtualBox Shared Folders"). Under "VirtualBox Shared Folders" there are all shares defined in VirtualBox. It is enough to install "guest additions". In KVM-QEMU it looks a bit more complicated, one should install these "guest additions" manually, see for example https://www.debugpoint.com/kvm-share-folder-windows-guest/